# Null class when deserializing Json C#

Tags: c#, json, class, serialization, null

I have this PHP

```
            if ($result->num_rows === 1) {
                    $sql = ("SELECT username, email, plan, activationdate, terminationdate FROM users WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1");
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if ($res->num_rows === 1) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)){
$arr = array( $row);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

which returns this json correctly [{"username":"xxxxx","email":"xxxxxx","plan":"0","activationdate":"","terminationdate":""}]

Now in c# i tried to deserialize using
`List<Information> resinfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Information>>(str2);` and returns null value

Note that in the pic [Null result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/421MQ.png) but the json string is retunrning value as intended [Json string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD6hP.png)

And this is my class

```
public class Information
{

    public static string username { get; set; }
    public static string email { get; set; }
    public static string plan { get; set; }
    public static string activationdate { get; set; }
    public static string terminationdate { get; set; }
}
```

Why am I getting null when I try to deserialize into the class and how can I deserialize correctly?

Its worth mentioning that I tried this `var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Information>>(str2);` with the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because all your properties in your `Information` class are `static`. Remove static keyword and try it again.

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` will set only instance properties so they cannot be declared as static.

After execution take a look at `removedFines` variable (as in [your image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/421MQ.png)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Removing `static` gives the following ![Image](https://prnt.sc/w2ov1u). (I changed the variable to make it more readable)

Comment: It is null because it is not executed. Try to put breakpoint a one line under and then take a look at result. If you dont have any code under, just put there var test = 1; for example.

Comment: Thank you. It does now return the correct values. One last question. Say that I want to use the string in "username" and display it in a label in another form, or user control in this case. How should I do that. Because simply calling `label1.text = Information.username` from the user control wont work. Thats why I had the properties static in the first place.

Comment: In your case it is a List of Information. You have to call UiInfo[0].username that means you will show username of first information class in your list.

Comment: If you want to show it in another form you can pass it as a parameter or you can make your list static (but this is not a good approach).

Comment: Thank you for all your responses. Could you please give a example in code? Im new to C# and sill learning. Correct me if Im wrong, my idea is to pass the string from my variable "Uinfo" to the parameters in the class. Now, I have a usercontrol called dashboardcontrol. What I want to do is in that control set a label and display the username in that label as well as the email and so on. How can I accomplish that? ![This is one class](https://prnt.sc/w2r5iv) , ![This is oneanother class](https://prnt.sc/w2r7ha) , ![This is my control](https://prnt.sc/w2r8h2)

Sorry for all the questions